# Maximum number of addressable LED's to be controlled by arduino

Tags: memory-management, arduino, microcontroller, led

I'm working on a project that involves building a big 'light wall' (h*w = 3,5 * 7 m). The wall is covered in semi-transparent fabric, and behind this is gonna be mounted strips of addressable RGB-LED's. The strips are gonna be mounted vertically and function as a big display for showing primitive graphics and visuals. I plan to control the diodes using an arduino. The reason for the choice of the arduino as controller is that is must be easily programmable, (relatively) cheap, and should work as a part of different interaction design setups.

[Current version of the light wall (without addressable LED's)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3FgT.jpg)

My ultimate concern is now this:
**How many individual diodes can I control before the arduino becomes inadequate?**

As I see it this comes down to two points:

- *When does the update rate of the diodes become too slow?* I want to update the picture at a rate of minimum 10 Hz.
- *When will the arduino run out of memory?* The state of all the diodes on the light wall should be stored for the next frame. At some point then the memory (256 KB for the arduino MEGA 2560) will run out. How many diodes can I control before this happens?

I realize that both questions are related to how the arduino is programmed. I am very open to any tips regarding speed optimization and memory conservation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do the math?  I don't mean to be flippant, but you haven't mentioned what the light strips are, how many you want, etc.   Once you know that, find out how long it takes to update a single strip, multiply it out, etc.   Same thing for the memory required.

Comment: You overlooked a third point: will there be enough execution time to update X outputs at Y frequency?

Comment: IMHO an arduino mega will not be enough for this. Assuming that you want to put one led every 2cm, they are about 60k leds. If each led is 2 bytes (65k colors) and you need 10 frames per second it's more than 1.2MB/s, or 10Mb/s. IMHO it's better to jump to another embedded platform (I know that ST has some 10eur platforms at 180MHz, but you'll have to write your own libraries since they are not arduino-compatible) or try to parallelize the load using more mega boards - but I think that even 10 boards will not be enough.

Comment: Also don't confuse RAM (8k) memory for flash (256k).  Application goes in flash, state information will be in RAM...